# How to specify a None for an Optional lifted column

Tags: sql, scala, join, slick

Say I have some tables with some association like so:

```
val ca = for {
  customer <- customers
  account <- accounts // if (... some complex logic here ---)
} yield (customer, account)
```

Now I want to join a table to these under some specific circumstances:

```
val one = for {
  result <- ca joinRight products on (_._1.name === _.name)
} yield result
```

I'm forcibly going to get a result of the following structure:

```
Query[(Rep[Option[(Customers, Accounts)]], Products), (Option[(CustomersRow, AccountsRow)], ProductsRow), scala.Seq]
```

How do I filter out the non-existing (Customers,Accounts) records and change the output to this?

```
Query[(Customers, Accounts, Products), (CustomersRow, AccountsRow, ProductsRow), scala.Seq]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same way you wrote the first join with customers and accounts.

```
val ca = for {
  customer <- customers
  account <- accounts // if (... some complex logic here ---)
  product <- products if (customer.name === product.name)
} yield (customer, account, product)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `joinLeft` should return you

```
Query[((Customers, Accounts), Rep[Option[Products]]), ((CustomersRow, AccountsRow), Option[ProductsRow]), scala.Seq]
```

that is `Seq[((CustomersRow, AccountsRow), Option[ProductsRow])]` and then you do whatever you want with `Option[ProductsRow]` etc...